# Concern about backing up MySQL DB using mysqldump

Tags: php, mysql, security, cron, backup

If I were to create a MySQL DB backup using mysqldump, and call it using a PHP 'system' or similar function, I have to include the password in the line, in order to automate it.

I can then (for example), either call the php function manually (i.e, through a link) or run it as a cron job.

**My concern:**

1. Given that the DB is on Ubuntu (Server), or another Linux flavour, wouldn't this be a bad idea since the next person logging in to the server will recognise the DB password?
2. Obviously, we're not talking about the root password. So the second part of the question is, what privileges could be given to a user account that would only be used to do backups?

Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I'm not sure if it should go on serverfault since my question concerns PHP as well. That's why I put it here.

Comment: @ChristopheD - It does not seem right, besides, serverfault you do not get as many answers as here, if at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the password into a file with appropriately locked-down privileges, then do

```
cat passwd.txt|mysqldump -p  dump_options_here
```

At minimum, you'd need SELECT, LOCK_TABLES, and possibly RELOAD if you're in a replication situation and need to flush logs.

Comment: Yes, that's the workaround I think I'll use :)
And it being a Linux OS we could do this quite easily.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't you put the DB password in a PHP file (or ini file) anyway for your real application? 
Don't you have a phpmyadmin installed (and in it's configuration file you can see the passwords un-encrypted)?

Comment: Yes, this is also an option. And as long as we stick to Ubuntu/Linux, I don't think the config files is going to be accessible by all. Thanks for the thought!